# Android components on phone position not matching on android studio

Tags: java, android, button, constraints

The position of the buttons on my phone are not the same as viewed in Android Studio.
Below is the XML for the button. Each button i've assigned the same constraint but moved it in a different position by dragging. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.734"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.265" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.519" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.734"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.519" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.28"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.265" />
```

[image]

and this is the view on my phone. SAMSUNG J5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default emulator and it does not appear that your phone is a nexus 4. Try changing your horizontal bias to be relative to the location of the other buttons and not an exact number.

```
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button12"
```

Without the rest of your code i am unable to test this for myself.